# Copiar dados da coluna de uma tabela para outra

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Tenho 2 tabelas

```
"Orcamento" -> colunas ['id', 'cliente_id']
Essa tabela existe valores em 'cliente_id'

"Ordem_servicos" -> colunas ['id', 'cliente_id', 'orcamento_id']
essa tabela não existe valores em 'cliente_id'
a coluna 'orcamento_id' refere-se a coluna 'id' da tabela "Orcamento"
```

preciso copiar os dados da coluna 'cliente_id' da tabela "Orcamento" para a tabela "ordem_servicos". mas usando o 'orcamento_id' pra especificar

tem que copiar o 'cliente_id' da coluna que o 'orcamento_id' seja igual a id da tabela "orcamentos"

tipo como estou tentando fazer mas não está funcionando.

```
    UPDATE ordem_servicos SET cliente_id = orcamentos.cliente_id
    FROM orcamentos 
    WHERE orcamentos.id = ordem_servicos.orcamento_id
```

Comment: pode especificar melhor o que vc precisa?

Comment: kkk.. sim mano vou refazer então..

Comment: blz. edita e me fala

Comment: pronto mano vê se agora ficou mais fácil entender

Comment: postei um exemplo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você precisa de um update com join. Algo assim (não testado, faça um backup do banco antes de rodar):

```
UPDATE Ordem_servicos os
INNER JOIN orcamentos AS o
ON o.id = os.orcamento_id
SET os.cliente_id = o.cliente_id;
```

Comment: deu erro mano..

Comment: #1064 - Você tem um erro de sintaxe no seu SQL próximo a 'FROM Ordem_Servicos AS os
INNER JOIN orcamentos AS o
ON o.id = os.orcamento_id' na linha 3

Comment: Atualizei, tente de novo. Nunca lembro de cabeça isso.

Comment: fez a água virar vinho mano.. só deu ambíguo porque faltou depois de SET colocar os.cliente_id

Comment: Isso :) Bom que deu certo

Comment: kkkk.. monstro! vlw mano sucesso!